# TTY virtual console + tmux: seems like ~/.bashrc is getting run more than once?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, console, bashrc

I prefer to use tmux rather than the default linux virtual console (i.e. what `agetty` uses), so I put this in `~/.bashrc` so that tmux runs automatically when I log in to a TTY:

```bsh
if [[ "$(tty)" == /dev/tty* ]]; then
    tmux -u
fi
```

At first it seems like this works: tmux runs as soon as I login. However, when I exit tmux, tmux immediately runs a second time! Here is the complete behavior:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
- Log in
- Default prompt briefly visible before tmux runs
- I'm in `tmux`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
- The text `[exited]` briefly flashes, and then I'm back in `tmux` again
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
- Back in default terminal without `tmux`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
- Now I'm completely logged out

I can't track this down - I've tried logging all sorts of things, setting environment variables, looking at `$SHLVL`. It actually looks like `.bashrc` gets run like 7 times each time I log in!

I don't normally use tmux from within X (I just use Konsole), but I tried setting  bashrc to have tmux run for all non-tmux sessions, and this double behavior did *not* happen in Konsole.

I'm using:

- Arch Linux (4.8.13-1)
- agetty
- tmux
- Bashish
- full `~/.bashrc` and other configs (no `~/.bash_profile` file): https://gist.github.com/tobek/c8038c207f318528c3157b4a402aa2d9 (I tried removing bashish stuff, but behavior remained)

What on could be causing this?

Comment: `agetty` does not produce virtual terminals.  It _uses_ terminal devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix #1:**

Couldn't track it down but managed to fix this with the following hack in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -z "$user_bashrc_already_run" ]; then
    export user_bashrc_already_run=1
else
    return
fi
```

---

**Fix #2:**

Managed to track this down properly. Since TTY is an interactive login shell it was running both `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` (terminal emulator in X loads neither, since it's not a login shell). In my case (and I have no idea why, maybe Bashish installation or something else) those files were identical, and both source all the scripts in `/etc/profile.d`, which in  my case included one script which sources `~/.bashrc`.

Removing all the duplicate code from `~/.profile` fixed the problem.

Reading the "Invocation" section from `man bash` and questions like https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc are useful.

---

In case anyone lands here with a similar issue, here is a better way to run tmux, because it causes the shell to be replaced with tmux instead of running tmux as a sub shell:

```bash
if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then # check if tmux command exists
    if [[ "$(tty)" =~ /dev/tty ]] && [[ ! "$TERM" =~ screen ]] && [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
        # We're on a TTY and *not* in tmux
        exec tmux -u
    fi
fi
```

And I decided to put this in my `~/.profile` because I want this running on login shells, not non-login shells. (Note that if you have `~/.bash_profile`, bash will run that instead of `~/.profile`.)

Comment: `agetty` has nothing to do with `.profile`.  Neither do the terminal emulators.  This is _all_ the doings of _your shell_.  You've been merrily setting things up to work with non-login interactive shells, not taking into account how things work with login shells.

Comment: Read the `bash` man page to see how it loads from the various rc files on startup.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - feel like I've gone over these things a dozen times and it hasn't stuck (but hopefully this exercise has done the trick). I've updated my answer with the real root cause of the problem, and hopefully made it more... accurate overall.